# Trouble whis the output of my webscraping script

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, csv, web-scraping

Here's my script :

To bypass datadome, I used it not at once, first :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait     
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By     
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


PATH = "chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument('enable-logging')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)

driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})

url = 'https://www.leboncoin.fr/voitures/offres'

driver.get(url)
```

Then I make manually the protection, then second part :

```
cookie = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="didomi-notice-agree-button"]')
try:
    cookie.click()
except:
    pass

time.sleep(2)


car = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@autocomplete="search-keyword-suggestions"]')
car.click()
car.send_keys('Peugeot')
car.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)

for x in range(10):
    #time.sleep(3)
    
    links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="_137P- P4PEa _35DXM"]')
    
    for l in links:
        data = l.text
        #x = data.split("/n")
        print(data)
        
    links2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@data-qa-id="aditem_title"]')
    
    for i in links2:
        data2 = i.text
        #x = data.split("/n")
        print(data2)
        print(data2)
        print(data2)
        print(data2)
        print(data2)

    links3 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="sc-jlyJG loRlDv"]')

    for j in links3:
        data3 = j.get_attribute("href")
        #x = data.split("/n")
        print(data3)
        print(data3)
        print(data3)
        print(data3)
        print(data3)

    links4 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="_2k43C Dqdzf cJtdT _3j0OU"]')

    for k in links4:
        data4 = k.text
        #x = data.split("/n")
        print(data4)
        print(data4)
        print(data4)
        print(data4)
        print(data4)
        
    next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Page suivante"]')

    next.click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

But, as you can see, my code isn't optimal. I obtained something like that :

```
7 490 €
2015
52000 km
Essence
Manuelle
...
Peugeot 407 hdi 2l exécutive 136cv
Peugeot 407 hdi 2l exécutive 136cv
Peugeot 407 hdi 2l exécutive 136cv
Peugeot 407 hdi 2l exécutive 136cv
Peugeot 407 hdi 2l exécutive 136cv
...
https://www.leboncoin.fr/voitures/2022493158.htm?ac=4051296304
https://www.leboncoin.fr/voitures/2022493158.htm?ac=4051296304
https://www.leboncoin.fr/voitures/2022493158.htm?ac=4051296304
https://www.leboncoin.fr/voitures/2022493158.htm?ac=4051296304
https://www.leboncoin.fr/voitures/2022493158.htm?ac=4051296304
...
Saint-Pardoux-Corbier 19210
Saint-Pardoux-Corbier 19210
Saint-Pardoux-Corbier 19210
Saint-Pardoux-Corbier 19210
Saint-Pardoux-Corbier 19210
```

I need to c/c manually into a csv file to obtained that :

[image: output]

But that not convenient at all. If you have a way to obtain this csv immediately, that would be awesome.

Comment: Why being so rude ? I always try solution provided to me. Sometime it work, sometime not and I post another message with my updated work. It's possible I forgot to accept answer somtime tho but just tell me I don't know. That's kind of mean.

Comment: For example, I posted on stackoverflow few days ago for a similar problem, someone provided me with a solution but it didn't work, why would I accept it ?

Comment: Sometime I tried several days until it work and then I accept but I like to have some other proposition meanwhile

Comment: If so it's OK, sorry

Comment: No problem, I understand your point of view Prophet. My case needed explanations :)

Comment: Sorry again. Giving upvote ;)